# Open only specific image to picturebox without opening File Dialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, picturebox

I'm using WinForms. In my form i have a picturebox, and a button. I'm trying to load a picture in my picturebox on button click from a file inside my computer. I don't want to open a file dialog-box. Every time i try to to open the image, i receive an error.

> Error Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dl

There is only one picture which has a .png extension in my image folder. Is there a way for me to just open .png picture in my picturebox without specifying the file name? I think i might be able to do this with just specifying the file extension. In this case something like C\image.png. How would i do this?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"‪‪C:\\image\\resized_tree.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: You should include your images in your application and from there specify the path something like "/images/resized_tree.jpg"

Comment: I cant do that for a couple reasons. These images are temporarily placed in my image folder from another application. I'm using my application to just view these images. @Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @".\";
        string[] filename = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png");

        pictureBox1.Load(filename[0]);
    }
```

Comment: How will this know to look inside my C:\image\ to locate a .png picture. Would i need to specify it?

Comment: set `path` to whatever you need. In my code snippet, it is set to "current folder", but it could be any folder you need.

Comment: To be clear: make `path = @"C:\image\";` in your case.

Comment: I tried this. I got an error under pictureBox1.Load(filename[0]); Error: Index Out Of Range Exception was unhandled. An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Load_Image_FROM_FIle.exe

Comment: it means `filename` is empty.... make sure the `png` file is in the folder you're reading from.

Comment: also make sure you're using the correct extension: either `png` or `jpg`. In your post you mentioned both of them...

Comment: Ahh Thank you. I learned a lot from you and even what the error meant. I appreciate your time helping me out.

Comment: You can also use FileStream

Comment: Glad to help, congrats!

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned above you cannot include your images to your existing application. You can load your images thru FIleStream.

Below Sample

```
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"‪‪C:\\image\\resized_tree.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   picturebox1.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);
```